# Want to send SMS from jsp, but not able to do so

Tags: java, http

I want to send SMS from Java code through a service provider's gateway using HTTP connection, but I get an error as given below.

```
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
```

I have two Ubuntu servers one for testing and another for deployment. The test server gives the error, while the other executes and sends the SMS.

Comment: Simple: test server is not allowed to connect to that service gateway (blocked on a firewall, probably).

Answer (score 0):

Test with a third party app, say curl in bash, maybe something like:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://serviceprovideraddress.com:3000/api/sendsms
```

Here some instructions on how you can test with Curl:

http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-test-a-rest-api-from-command-line-with-curl/

check if you have any firewall restrictions on your system.

Try pinging the host first see if you get an ip address back. If not check your DNS settings, or may be simply a record in your /etc/hosts file:

46.4.24.210 promo.smsfresh.co

Comment: I tried using curl, but got the same error msg:  curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'promo.smsfresh.co'

Comment: @SatishD "Couldn't resolve host" is not the same as "Connection refused".

Comment: What are the things that I would have to look into to over come this problem. Since I know nothing about server settings, a details explanation would be more helpful to me.

Comment: Couldn't resolve host means that the system could not locate the server at promo.smsfresh.co, ask yourself a few questions, can you ping it? (ping promo.smsfresh.co) is your DNS settings correct? Try different DNS settings. Add a record in your hosts file at /etc/hosts.